# PHP- file get contents & cURL not displaying anything

Tags: php, api, curl

I checked and it looks like cURL is enabled inside the php.ini file (I'm using XAMPP) and yet it's still not displaying anything. Same thing goes for file_get_contents. I simply get a blank web page as a result...

```
<body>
<?php
$auth = base64_encode("04d2ac7f76a0fbc0eee9dc5ef96b9259:dc70ffc7ad911236bc2e0822855e2d42");
$context = stream_context_create(['http' => ['header' => "Authorization: Basic $auth"]]);
$homepage = file_get_contents("https://api.intrinio.com/companies?identifier=AA", false, $context );


$login = '04d2ac7f76a0fbc0eee9dc5ef96b9259';
$password = 'dc70ffc7ad911236bc2e0822855e2d42';
$url = 'https://api.intrinio.com/companies?identifier=AA';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$login:$password");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);  
echo($result);
?>
</body>
```

Anyone has an idea why?
Thanks!

Comment: And what does your PHP error log tell you?

Comment: Take a look at [how to enable error reporting here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display?rq=1) and see if you get some error output that helps you. Also, you probably can remove the `<body></body>` part there.

Comment: Removed the unnecessary html tags and checked if error reporting is on in the php.ini- it is. Also, added this to the code:
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL); but still nothing- empty page.

Comment: I put your code in a test.php file and ran in localhost on MAMP and it works fine.

Comment: I hope your auth token/key is disposable.

Comment: I see. So what am I supposed to do now then? Is it a problem with XAMPP/my network or something? Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: @deR_Ed answer is what you should be doing, you need to confirm if your local environment is halting on errors.

Comment: I'm not getting anything back when I do what he mentions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
$auth = base64_encode("04d2ac7f76a0fbc0eee9dc5ef96b9259:dc70ffc7ad911236bc2e0822855e2d42"); 
$context = stream_context_create(['http' => ['header' => "Authorization: Basic $auth"]]); 
$homepage = file_get_contents("https://api.intrinio.com/companies?identifier=AA", false, $context ); 
$jsonary = json_decode($homepage,TRUE); 
print_r($jsonary);
```

That said, curl still isn't working so if someone has an idea on how to fix it then I'd still appreciate if you could let me know.